# ServiceStack Redis Exception with SortedSet

Tags: .net, redis, servicestack

I have a question related to ServiceStack Redis client.
It's very simple scenario, I have a backend job to analyze search keywords and terms, I want to add those terms to a sorted list.
the solution is very simple, Redis client with  a loop to add items to sorted set.
When testing it on my local machine redis instance, I always get exception after inserting 6021 items.
Then I thought it could be a configuration on my local machine, so I tried that with Azure Redis instance, and the same exception occurred.
I have no explanation for it, is it bug in Redis ServiceStack library, is it a Redis configuration limitation, am I using the right approach?

any help is most appreciated.
Thanks

**Program**

```
  var setId = "terms";
        Stopwatch sw=new Stopwatch();
        using (var client = new RedisClient())
        {
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                client.AddItemToSortedSet(setId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
            }
            sw.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Saving time: {0}",sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

**Exception**

> Unhandled Exception: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException: Unable to Connect:
>       sPort
>       : 1238
>          at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.CreateConnectionError()
>          at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendReceive[T](Byte[][] cmdWithBinary
>       Args, Func`1 fn, Action`1 completePipelineFn, Boolean sendWithoutRead)
>          at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectLong(Byte[][] cmdWithBinary
>       Args)
>          at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ZAdd(String setId, Double score, Byte
>       [] value)
>          at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.AddItemToSortedSet(String setId, String val
>       ue, Double score)
>          at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.AddItemToSortedSet(String setId, String val
>       ue)

Comment: If you're using the commercial ServiceStack v4 and haven't registered a license key, then it's likely you've hit the [free-quota limit](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas).

Comment: Thanks a lot that's probably the reason.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @mythz the reason behind the exception is related to the commercial license of ServiceStack:

[ServiceStack Free Quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas)